# Is it poor design to declare a class abstract because it only has static members?

Tags: java, static, singleton, abstract

I have a class in my project that is used to load external resources (namely, images and audio files). This class only has a few members: HashMap fields for storing resources, and `getImage(reference)`, etc. methods for retrieving the resources.

I originally implemented the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but then I read some criticisms on the linked page, and considered using static members.

Long after happily deciding to implement all the class functionality statically, I was doing some code cleanup. While doing this, I realized that nothing was stopping me from instantiating this `ResourceManager` class. This led me to tag it with the `abstract` keyword.

I've never used `abstract` in this way before; I've only ever applied it more conventionally for an inheritance tree. I tried Googling uses and misuses of `abstract`, but all the resources I found seemed either less-than-trustworthy, or didn't advise against the use of abstract in this way:

[Oracle's tutorial on abstract classes and methods.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) 
[Another site discussing the keyword.](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/abstract_class.html)

Quote from the second link: "Its purpose is to serve purely as a parent of classes."

Is my new implementation conventional, forgivable, or just plain wrong?

Comment: Making a class abstract means something else I feel like, but I can see why you have considered it in the first place. An abstact class should not be instantiated because it is missing concrete implementation details, since it has abstract mehtods. You would be better off hiding the constructor I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to make it abstract, just make the constructor **private**. **Abstract** tells developers that this class is meant for extending, which is not the case in your example.

```
private ResourceManager() {
}
```

Comment: Ah, how did I not think to do this? +1 for re-iterating the self-documenting properties of abstract.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I'd just hide the constructor like this:

```
private ResourceManager() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it poor design to declare a class abstract because it only has static members?

Yes.

Make it final and provide it with only a private constructor.